How to slide cement board into notches under water heater


I removed some damaged drywall, which was covering the pictured insulation. I am replacing it with cement board and need to avoid gaps over 1/8" so mice can't get into the house through the water heater closet. (This is my garage.)
But I can't just slide the cement board down into the space. The framing creates corners i have to get into. There are 1-inch deep slats, essentially, on each side, each about 7/8 inch wide. The overall space to fill is 20" x 26".
The cement board is a half inch thick.. the only thing I have thought of is to cut it into two pieces and install them so I create a vertical seam down the middle. But then I would need to put trim over the middle. So I am looking for other ideas

what'e the problem with trim?

This picture needs more explanation and some arrows. "I am replacing the drywall that was here": We don't know where it was, please show us. "There are 1-inch deep slats ... on each side": Please draw arrows to the slats. As Bart van Ingen Schenau's answer "If this is just to cover up the bottom part" shows, we have to guess as to what you mean, which makes this question not a good fit for DIY.SE.

ignoring the elephant in the room.  what happened to the drip tray?

I see the gaps you intend to fill. Measure the board to fit the desired place, snap it in two, fit the two pieces separately. Tape them together.

install something to fix the edges of the board to, eg 1.5" slats behind the sides of where the board goes.
Use something flexible like steel sheet or thin cement board instead of halfinch cement board in this location.

Thank you, flexible galvanized steel sounds like a great solution. The drywall i removed got wet when a TSP valve malfunctioned, so it would be great to have something waterproof in that spot. If I use a regular drill with a carbide bit, I guess I will just get as close to the corners as I can to prevent bowing?

you could do 2 layers of 1/8" cement board and put glue between the layers for improved stiffness

This answer was written before it became clear that the channel for the board was not formed by the door frame, but is only cut out of the frame for the height of the panel. That new information invalidates the answer for this case, but I am leaving it up for others with a situation where the solution can work.

If this is just to cover up the bottom part, below the plateau of the water heater, I would approach it like this.

cut the cement board to size, so it will fit the channels created by the door frame with just a little play.
try to insert the board at the level of the water heater. Use the space around the water heater to maneuver the board into the door frame. If it gets stuck diagonally in the door frame, cut small strips from the board and taper the edges so it can just make the turn.
slide the board down into position
if the board is too loose in its position for your comfort, add small strips of wood at one or both side to jam the board into place.


I can't slide the board down bc of the top corners shown where the doorframe meets the vertical framing under the water heater. I don't understand how the original drywall was all one piece. They must have built the doorframe after installing that now-removed piece of drywall

@user244083, that wasn't clear from your original picture. The picture you wanted to add to this answer as explanation I have added to the question instead.
